# how to properly single out cell accessory view

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

So my goal is to properly separate the cells accessory. Here is my first set of cells when the segment control is at the first index. The accessory type is a normal disclosure indicator.

[image: image1]

Now when I switch the value of the segment index, i set my cells with a custom accessory view.

[image: image2]

Now the issue is when I switch back to the first segment, the custom accessory view comes over to the first 2 cells as well like so :

[image: image3]

I just want to figure out how I can prevent this from happening and keep the cell accessories properly separated. I will attach my necessary code for the issue.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.CellDetails.studentDashCell, for: indexPath)
    let cellImage = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.seal.fill")
    let cellImageView = UIImageView(image: cellImage)
    cellImageView.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4666666687, green: 0.7647058964, blue: 0.2666666806, alpha: 1)
    cellImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    
    
    
    if selectorOfEvents.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Constants.AppFonts.consistentFont, size: 22)
        cell.textLabel?.text = gothereEvents[indexPath.row].eventName
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    } else if selectorOfEvents.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Constants.AppFonts.menuTitleFont, size: 22)
        cell.textLabel?.text = gotherePurchasedEventNames[indexPath.row].purchasedEventName
        cell.accessoryView = cellImageView
        

    }
    
    return cell
}
```

The `cellForRowAt()` method. ^

```
 @IBAction func eventsSegmented(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        navigationItem.title = "Events"
        tableView.reloadData()

     
    } else {
        navigationItem.title = "Purchased Events"
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
}
```

The `IBAction` func for the segmented control. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your very kind words. @dfd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion is that the accessory view / type is getting carried over on some dequeued cells. You should explicitly set both the `accessoryView` and `cell.accessoryType` type in both cases:

```
if selectorOfEvents.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Constants.AppFonts.consistentFont, size: 22)
        cell.textLabel?.text = gothereEvents[indexPath.row].eventName
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        cell.accessoryView = nil //<-- here
    } else if selectorOfEvents.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Constants.AppFonts.menuTitleFont, size: 22)
        cell.textLabel?.text = gotherePurchasedEventNames[indexPath.row].purchasedEventName
        cell.accessoryView = cellImageView
        cell.accessoryType = .none //<-- here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man, works great, always helping a brother out. Appreciate it.  @jnpdx